# Google Maps error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I use Google Maps in Android Studio. Everything is working fine but in the console, I have an error:

```
07-02 10:53:54.191  29293-29293/com.home.smart.home E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
07-02 10:53:54.192  29293-29293/com.home.smart.home E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
07-02 10:53:55.831  29293-29293/com.home.smart.home E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ij.a
07-02 10:53:55.868  29293-29293/com.home.smart.home E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ij.b
```

I have included lib in Gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Comment: Please post the code where it is failing.

Comment: @JamieRees apps not falling, its work but console i have this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the full stack trace I can't be sure, but I suppose you are trying to use big notification on a device that does not support them. Which API level are you using?
Minsdk
TargetSDk
and deviceSDk

I think you are developing for targetsdk >= 16 and your device is older (maybe a gingerbread?

Comment: i have this  `compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.home.smart.home"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }`

Comment: If the app work with no crash, you dont have to worry, its Google code that maybe tryes to use non available api